# AdMob - dfpadview - stretch / shrink to fill android phone screen?

Tags: android, admob

having an issue with the width not filling the screen up on Android devices.

Here is part of our xml:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/adViewContainer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="horizontal"
                       android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                       android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                       android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                       android:background="#00000000" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Here is our code for the banner, it's 320 by 60 (it is html content).  Because of varying phone sizes, sometimes it's cut off, sometimes it's too small... Any recommendations you guys have on how to shrink/stretch it to fill all the space of heigh = 60, width = whatever screen is?

```
AdSize customAdSize = new AdSize(320, 60);

adView = new DfpAdView(this, customAdSize, AdURL);
adView.setAppEventListener(this);

AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adViewContainer);

adContainer.addView(adView);
adView.setAdListener(this);
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Have you found a solution to this since I am facing similar issues too. Thanks